# ssis unicode flatfile processing by script component

Tags: sql-server, string, vb.net, unicode, ssis

I have an awkward flat file input that can be virtually any length. This is a comma delimited file, but has embedded tables delimited by "[{" and "}]" or "{" and "}" .. depending on the table type. I cannot use the off the shelf SSIS comma delimited flat file as there may be records with no embedded tables at all. 
To get around this I've set the flat file input to be ragged right and with one column of 8,000 characters.

I've then done the string splitting in a script component and output the table data to separate output streams.

However, I am now receiving files that exceed 8000 characters which has broken my process.

I've tried converting the flat file from "1252 (ANSI Latin 1)" into unicode with the column in NTEXT.

I've then inserted the following code to convert this to a string
See http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/09/convert-text-stream-to-string/

```
  Dim TextStream As Byte()            ' To hold Text Stream
  Dim TextStreamAsString As String    ' To Hold Text Stream converted to String
    ' Load Text Stream into variable
     TextStream = Row.CopyofColumn0.GetBlobData(0, CInt(Row.CopyofColumn0.Length))

    ' Convert Text Stream to string
     TextStreamAsString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(TextStream)
```

But when I look at the string I get appear to get a lot of kanji type characters and no line feeds.

Any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: Usually files like this use a different delimiter in the table column. If so, treat the column as a string and parse it to an array using split. And send that data to a different output dataflow along with the key to the source table.

Comment: @keithL I have no problem splitting the data. I just cannot read it when it is 8,000+ characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a flat file source, you could just use a script source component that opens the file with a file system object.

Comment: @taballernan Could you point me towards a useful guide? I've used the filesystemobject extensively in VBA but have never tried this in VB.net. In the meantime I'll continue trawling Google to see if I can find a solution myself

Comment: I don't know of any particular guide off hand.   Googling for `FileSystemObject Tutorial ` in the language of your choice should do the trick.   BTW, there's very little difference in the way you use the FSO in VBA vs VB.net, so you should have little trouble.

Answer (score 2):

As I found it difficult finding an exact match to using the filesystemobject in an SSIS vb.net script component source transformation, I thought I'd share my findings!

The following imports are required

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
```

and the code ..

```
 Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()
<Output Name>Buffer".
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strFileContent As String
    Dim objFileInfo As FileInfo
    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader

    Try
        strFilePath = "c:\myfile.csv" 'Me.Variables.FullFilePath
        objFileInfo = New FileInfo(strFilePath)
        objStreamReader = New StreamReader(strFilePath)
        Do Until objStreamReader.EndOfStream
            strFileContent = objStreamReader.ReadLine               
            Process_data(strFileContent) ' do the work in this a sub!
        Loop            
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Note: I use a foreach loop to obtain the filename in my script. The hard coded filepath here is just as an example.